# Aggregate NodeID totals in report

Tags: sql, performance, query-performance, solarwinds-orion

I've been having trouble with editing my current query to get the total of all interfaces and `interfaceID`'s associated with a single `nodeID` to show on one row.

More specifically, I want to get the sum of the `MAXIMUM INPUT BPS (90)`, `MAXIMUM INPUT BPS (95)`, `MAXIMUM INPUT BPS (99)`, and other relevant columns.  For instance, for `nodeID = 113`, there are multiple `interfaceID`'s associated to that `nodeID` and therefore will output the results to have multiple rows for `nodeID = 113`.

What I want to do is get the sum of the `MAXIMUM INPUT BPS (90)` and other numerical columns to be displayed in one singular row for `nodeID = 113` and show the numerical outputs (I'm fine with removing the `interfaceID`'s and interface name columns).

I'll be attaching an image of the current report to help clear things up for what I have now based off of the query I have written:

[image: Report Output]

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. If you can post your current query that you are having problems with, we can help you better.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am allowed to do that as I have just added onto the query given by SolarWinds, the application I'm using for this sort of reporting.

Comment: I'd need to see more of your SWQL code to work this out. What table(s) are your querying. Is there a Thwack post, where you've upload it?

Answer (score 0):

SolarWinds Query Language (SWQL) supports aggregate functions such as SUM that you can use here to obtain the result that you are looking for.

```
SELECT NodeID, SUM([MAX INPUT BPS(90)])
FROM 
<TableName>
GROUP BY NodeID
```

Please let me know if this helps answer your question.

To see what's supported by SWQL, you can visit this [page](https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Network_Performance_Monitor_(NPM)/Knowledgebase_Articles/How_to_use_SolarWinds_Query_Language_(SWQL))

Comment: I tried "SELECT 

    Interfaces.InterfaceId,
    Nodes.NodeID,
    NodeName,
    SUM(Interface_Caption),
    SUM(Maxbps_In90),
    SUM(Maxbps_Out90),
    SUM(Maxbps_In95),
    SUM(Maxbps_Out95),
    SUM(Maxbps_In99),
    SUM(Maxbps_Out99)" and ended with GROUP BY Nodes.NodeID and had no budge. This is just a code snippet but I can direct message you the rest if you need it.